# failed to get TestNG version from class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.internal.Version

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

How to resolve this issue?

failed to get TestNG version from class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.internal.Version

Comment: Please post some code that is causing this error.

Comment: What version of TestNG are you using?